# Comparing gather (tidyr) to melt (reshape2)

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

I love the **reshape2** package because it made life so doggone easy.  Typically Hadley has made improvements in his previous packages that enable streamlined, faster running code.  I figured I'd give **tidyr** a whirl and from what I read I thought `gather` was very similar to `melt` from **reshape2**.  But after reading the documentation I can't get `gather` to do the same task that `melt` does.

**Data View**

Here's a view of the data (actual data in `dput` form at end of post):

```
  teacher yr1.baseline     pd yr1.lesson1 yr1.lesson2 yr2.lesson1 yr2.lesson2 yr2.lesson3
1       3      1/13/09 2/5/09      3/6/09     4/27/09     10/7/09    11/18/09      3/4/10
2       7      1/15/09 2/5/09      3/3/09      5/5/09    10/16/09    11/18/09      3/4/10
3       8      1/27/09 2/5/09      3/3/09     4/27/09     10/7/09    11/18/09      3/5/10
```

**Code**

Here's the code in `melt` fashion, my attempt at `gather`.  How can I make `gather` do the same thing as `melt`?

```
library(reshape2); library(dplyr); library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
   melt(id=c("teacher", "pd"), value.name="date") 

dat %>% 
   gather(key=c(teacher, pd), value=date, -c(teacher, pd))
```

**Desired Output**

```
   teacher     pd     variable     date
1        3 2/5/09 yr1.baseline  1/13/09
2        7 2/5/09 yr1.baseline  1/15/09
3        8 2/5/09 yr1.baseline  1/27/09
4        3 2/5/09  yr1.lesson1   3/6/09
5        7 2/5/09  yr1.lesson1   3/3/09
6        8 2/5/09  yr1.lesson1   3/3/09
7        3 2/5/09  yr1.lesson2  4/27/09
8        7 2/5/09  yr1.lesson2   5/5/09
9        8 2/5/09  yr1.lesson2  4/27/09
10       3 2/5/09  yr2.lesson1  10/7/09
11       7 2/5/09  yr2.lesson1 10/16/09
12       8 2/5/09  yr2.lesson1  10/7/09
13       3 2/5/09  yr2.lesson2 11/18/09
14       7 2/5/09  yr2.lesson2 11/18/09
15       8 2/5/09  yr2.lesson2 11/18/09
16       3 2/5/09  yr2.lesson3   3/4/10
17       7 2/5/09  yr2.lesson3   3/4/10
18       8 2/5/09  yr2.lesson3   3/5/10
```

**Data**

```
dat <- data.frame(
  teacher = factor(c("3", "7", "8")),
  yr1.baseline = factor(c("1/13/09", "1/15/09", "1/27/09")),
  pd = factor(c("2/5/09", "2/5/09", "2/5/09")),
  yr1.lesson1 = factor(c("3/6/09", "3/3/09", "3/3/09")),
  yr1.lesson2 = factor(c("4/27/09", "5/5/09", "4/27/09")),
  yr2.lesson1 = factor(c("10/7/09", "10/16/09", "10/7/09")),
  yr2.lesson2 = factor(c("11/18/09", "11/18/09", "11/18/09")),
  yr2.lesson3 = factor(c("3/4/10", "3/4/10", "3/5/10"))
)
```

Comment: You might be interested in [this comparison of the reshape2 and tidyr +dplyr packages](http://rpubs.com/paul4forest/reshape2tidyrdplyr). I used the Air quality example and French Fries example to compare the usage of reshape2 melt() and dcast() functions to tidyr gather() and spread() functions combined with the dplyr group_by() and summarise() functions.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Your `gather` line should look like:

```
dat %>% gather(variable, date, -teacher, -pd)
```

This says "Gather all variables except `teacher` and `pd`, calling the new key column 'variable' and the new value column 'date'."

---

As an explanation, note the following from the `help(gather)` page:

```
 ...: Specification of columns to gather. Use bare variable names.
      Select all variables between x and z with ‘x:z’, exclude y
      with ‘-y’. For more options, see the select documentation.
```

Since this is an ellipsis, the specification of columns to gather is given as separate (bare name) arguments. We wish to gather all columns except `teacher` and `pd`, so we use `-`.

Comment: The syntax makes perfect sense now.  I just didn't see it before.  Thanks for the terrific response.

Comment: @BenBolker I like that better.  It helps me to group things in my brain.It could wind up being less keystrokes too.

Answer (score 12):

In tidyr 1.0.0 this task is accomplished with the more flexible `pivot_longer()`.

The equivalent syntax would be

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(teacher, pd), names_to = "variable", values_to = "date")
```

which says, correspondingly, "pivot everything longer except `teacher` and `pd`, calling the new variable column "variable" and the new value column "date".

Note that the long data comes back in order firstly of the columns of the previous data frame that were pivoted, unlike from `gather`, which came back in the order of the new variable column. To rearrange the resultant tibble, use `dplyr::arrange()`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
    dat%>%
    gather(!c(teacher,pd),key=variable,value=date)
```