# In tidyr, what criteria does the function `gather` use to map a dataframe from wide to long?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape2, tidyr

I'm trying to figure out the arguments for `gather` in the `tidyr` package.

I looked at the documentation, and the syntax looks like:

`gather(data, key, value, ..., na.rm = FALSE, convert = FALSE)`

There is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060) in the help files:

```
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

gather(stocks, stock, price, -time)
```

I'm curious about the last line:
`gather(stocks, stock, price, -time)`

Here, `stocks` is clearly the data we want to modify, which is fine.

So I can read that `stock` and `price` are arguments to a key value pair -- but how does this function decide how to select columns to create this key value pair? The original dataframe looks like this:

```
time        X            Y          Z
2009-01-01  1.10177950  -1.1926213  -7.4149618
2009-01-02  0.75578151  -4.3705737  -0.3117843
2009-01-03  -0.23823356 -1.3497319  3.8742654
2009-01-04  0.98744470  -4.2381224  0.7397038
2009-01-05  0.74139013  -2.5303960  -5.5197743
```

I don't see any indication that we should use any combination of `X`, `Y` or `Z`. When I'm using this function, I feel like I'm just choosing names for what I want the columns in my long formatted dataframe to be, and praying that `gather` magically works. Come to think of it, I feel the same way when I use `melt`.

Does `gather` look at the column's type? How does it map from wide to long?

**EDIT**
Great answer below, great discussion below, and for anyone else wanting more info on the philosophy and use of the `tidyr` package should definitely read this [paper](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html), although the vignette doesn't explain the syntax.

Comment: The `-time` says to use all the columns except time. Another approach would be to use `gather(stocks, stock, value, X:Z)`, if you prefer to specify which columns should be "gathered". Or even, `gather(stocks, stock, value, X, Y, Z)`. Essentially, this is more like using `melt` with `measure.vars` argument instead of specifying the `id.vars` (`melt(stocks, measure.vars = c("X", "Y", "Z"))`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In "tidyr", you specify the measure variables for `gather` in the `...` argument. This is a little bit different conceptually from `melt`, where many examples (even many answers here on SO) would show the use of the `id.vars` argument (with the assumption that anything that is not specified as an ID is a measurement).

The `...` argument can also take a `-` column name, as in the example you have shown. This basically says to "gather all of the columns except for this one". Another shorthand approach in `gather` includes specifying a range of columns by using the colon, for example, `gather(stocks, stock, price, X:Z)`.

You can compare `gather` with `melt` by looking at the code for the function. Here are the first few lines:

```
> tidyr:::gather_.data.frame
function (data, key_col, value_col, gather_cols, na.rm = FALSE, 
    convert = FALSE) 
{
    data2 <- reshape2::melt(data, measure.vars = gather_cols, 
        variable.name = key_col, value.name = value_col, na.rm = na.rm)
```

Comment: Hmm... That's funny that `gather` is just `melt` wrapper.. What was the point in creating it then?

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think that there's only one person who knows the answer to that. `spread` isn't just `dcast`, so perhaps this is just a template for now? It seems a little awkward to me that the overall philosophy between "reshape2" and "tidyr" diverge a fair amount, but perhaps that's why it's a totally different package....

Comment: @DavidArenburg the point is that `gather()` is in general, much easier for people to understand, and it's symmetric with `spread()` (unlike `melt()` and `cast()`)

Comment: @hadley I find `gather` way harder to understand than `dcast`. In `dcast` you were specifying *all* the variables in interest, while in `gather` you alway need to keep in mind that the ID column should be ignored for some reason. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536251/comparing-gather-tidyr-to-melt-reshape2/) illustrates pretty well the confusion. `dcast` was also  much more flexible the `spread` and had the `fun.aggregate` argument. It's just funny to me the hype around `tidyr` when it's both far less flexible/convenient and just a wrapper for `reshape2`...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I don't think your linked question is a great illustration. At some point, there's simply a different "philosophy" between the two approaches, and Tyler's question showed that he didn't understand the philosophy yet. Similarly, `spread` isn't designed to do everything that `dcast` does. Instead, it's expected to be a part of a "sentence" or a "paragraph" that describes how to manipulate the data, in which the aggregation step would be one of the earlier phrases.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I completely agree that `tidyr` is different "philosophy", I'm just arguing hadleys statement that it is *much easier for people to understand*, thus the linked question to illustrate my point. I'm saying only my opinion here, I do realize that it *is* possible that this easier for certain people.

Comment: @DavidArenburg all I can counter with is that my experience is that gather/spread fits most people's brains better, and anecdotally it's easier for most people to learn. The point of tidyr __is__ to do less than reshape2, but it's the right less. Have you read the tidy data paper?

Comment: @hadley, I once took a look, but it was long ago. Did you update it to match the new philosophy?

Comment: @DavidArenburg update is in vignette: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html

Comment: @DavidArenburg coming late to this, but I think some of your difficulty with gather/spread may be that you already understand melt/dcast. A shift in understanding can sometimes be more difficult than a first learn. I'm teaching an introductory R course now, and presented both. On the homework I gave where they could use either, most of the students tended toward the tidyr functions.

Comment: @Gregor, that's an interesting thought- I've actually encountered it myself too. The students course is also an interesting use case. I guess I'm already from the old generation then :).