# Melt a daframe with col names as values

Tags: r

From a dataframe like this:

```
dframe = data.frame(data = c(1), error = c(3))
```

How can we melt the data aiming to have the col names as values.

Here an example of expected output

```
 dframe_ex = data.frame(id=c("data","error"), num=c(1,3))
 dframe_ex
     id num
1  data   1
2 error   3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape from wide to long format/structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261492/reshape-from-wide-to-long-format-structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for base R's `stack`

```
stack(dframe)
#  values   ind
#1      1  data
#2      3 error
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
library(tidyr)
dframe %>%
  gather(id, num)
```

output is

```
     id num
1  data   1
2 error   3
```

Comment: Or just `library(tidyr)`, unless you need other packages from `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `melt` in `reshape2` :

```
library(reshape2)
dframe_ex <- melt(dframe)

> print(dframe_ex)
  variable value
1     data     1
2    error     3
```

If you want to have the col names you specified then:

```
library(tidyverse)
dframe_ex <- melt(dframe) %>% 
  rename(id = variable, num = value)
```

Comment: The package `reshape2` has now been deprecated in favour of `tidyr`

Comment: sure but since the OP did actually use the verb 'melt' and that the `reshape2` package still works, thought this would be of use.